# Using *_type? methods Rails polymorphic associations | Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, polymorphic-associations

Using the example found in [Polymorphic Associations](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations) found on [rubyonrails.org's Active Record Associations](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html), I've set up an association accordingly in a project. I'd like to be able to show a view element conditionally based on whether an `:imageable_type` is set to `"Employee"` or `"Product"`. Obviously, I cound say:

```
<% if @picture.imageable_type == "Employee" %>
  <p>Do stuff...</p>
<% end %>
```

But after running `> Picture.first.methods` I can see that `imageable_type?(*args)` is a method this association makes available, but I can't see any documentation on how to use it...

I tried these out, expecting to have a boolean returned:

`> Picture.first.imageable_type?(:employee)`
`> Picture.first.imageable_type?("Employee")`

but I got the error: `ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)`

```
2.4.0 :028 > Picture.first.imageable_type?(:employee)
  Picture Load (3.2ms)  SELECT  `pictures`.* FROM `pictures` ORDER BY `pictures`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)
    from (irb):28
```

Should I be parsing something else to the method? And better yet; is there any documentation of how to use these methods added by a polymorphic association?

Thanks

Comment: Can you try this ? `employee = Employee.first`
`Picture.where("pictures.imageable_type = ? AND pictures.imageable_id", "Employee", employee.id)`

Comment: If you only want to check the type of associated object, you can do `@picture.imageable.is_a?(Employee)`

Comment: Just because you saw a method doesn't mean it's for plain usage, that method can be for internal usage only, also `*args` mean an array of arguments.